# Spring Cloud Routing Based on Payload

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to implement the below pattern.

API Gateway:

> http://apigateway/serve-this-request

Service-A:

> http://service-a/v1/type1
>
> http://service-a/v1/type2

Service-B:

> http://service-b/v1/type2
>
> http://service-b/v1/type5

Service-C:

> http://service-c/v1/type3

**Scenario is:**

Only one endpoint I am going to expose from APIgateway and Based on the payload received at APIGateway I need to route the request to the specific service. If my payload contains service-a and type1 endpoint-related payload it needs to route the request to the http://service-a/v1/type1 endpoint. If the payload contains data related to service-b and type5 then it needs to route to http://service-b/v1/type5

I tried but was not able to find the solution. Please help.

Comment: Please look at the read body predicate

Comment: @spencergibb tried but no lock, could you please provide sample code

Comment: What did you try?